# formatOnSave doesn't work in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed C/C++ extensions, and added lines below to user settings:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
"C_Cpp.clang_format_path": "C:/Progra~2/LLVM/bin/clang-format.exe"
"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "LLVM"
"C_Cpp.clang_format_formatOnSave": true
```

but alt-shift-F, ctrl-s(save) both don't reformat codes at all.

I tried to remove vscode completely/reinstall/reboot, but didn't work.

And there's no workspace settings seperately.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Also your session:

```
// "Default" enables code formatting. "Disabled" disables code formatting.
   "C_Cpp.formatting": "Default",
```

should be 'Default' and not 'Disabled'.